# Pause MediaPlayer when using a Map in android app

Tags: android, dictionary, media-player

I am building a soundboard with about 40 sounds using a map.
[(Previous thread)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543361/imagebutton-soundboard-android-app/5543557#5543557)

Does anyone know a good way to pause restart Mediaplayer if the app is moved to the background (incoming call or anything like that)? I'm still very new at this so it is probably something super simple. Thanks anyone who can help.

> Map map = new
>
> HashMap();
>
> map.put(R.id.button1, R.raw.sound1);
>
> map.put(R.id.button2, R.raw.sound2);
>
> ...

and then iterate:

> for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
>
> ```
> final MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(entry.getValue());
>
> Button button = (ImageButton) findViewById(entry.getKey());
>
> button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>     @Override
>
>     public void onClick(View v) {
>
>         sound.start();
>
>     }
>
> });
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you don't want to play all sounds together, so you can declare the mediaplayer object outside the loop and then you don't need to know which file is being played. You can use `sound.pause();` `sound.stop();` or `sound.reset();` (depends on the action you want to preform) I suggest you look at the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) to see how to implement it properly.

If you want to create mediaplayer for each file *which I doubt you want*, save the mediaplayers in a map / list and pause / reset them in loop during `onPause()`.

Answer (score 0):

Override `Activity.onPause()`. This is called whenever your app goes to the background, Home button or back button or incoming call or magic thunderclouds of doom.

Comment: I have used that before, but I do not know how to stop the sound that is playing, because of the map I do not know an individual file to pause. lol doomclouds