# MediaPlayer and map issues android app (noob question)

Tags: android, dictionary, media-player

I'm just learning here. I'm trying to make a soundboard with around forty sounds, but I'm having some trouble how to get it to work using a maphash. Can anyone save me?

--------------soundboard-------------------------

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class main extends Activity {

MediaPlayer mp=null;

\\\if I put put "MediaPlayer mp;" here it only plays one sound\\\

ImageButton Button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    map.put(R.id.button1, R.raw.sound1);
    map.put(R.id.button2, R.raw.sound2);

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, entry.getValue()); 


 \\\if I put "final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, entry.getValue());" here I cant stop MediaPlayer with onpause and onstop overrides.\\\


        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(entry.getKey());
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }

        });
    }
}

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(mp.isPlaying()){ 
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
     public void onDestroy(){
     super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }

}
```

Comment: What are the problems you are facing?

Comment: @MByD 

Im not sure exactly how to word it because I'm still pretty new, but if. If I put "MediaPlayer mp;" right after activity but before "oncreate" i can only plays one of my many sounds. If I put "final MediaPlayer mp"  after "oncreate" sounds keep playing after the app is closed. I'm trying to get it to work both ways, so all the sounds work and so i can pause/stop/release if the app moves to the background. oh thanks and for your help on my last post i have been working at this for a few hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545593/pause-mediaplayer-when-using-a-map-in-android-app), don't create all those mediaplayer instances, for two reasons:

1. You lose all instances and have only the last one. always.
2. The onCreate() become very long method for no reason.

instead, remove `mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, entry.getValue());` from your for loop, and move it to inside of your listener, something like that (not tested...):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
            int sound = map.get(v.getId());
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(main.this, sound);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

So you would create the mediaplayer instance only when needed.

BTW, main is not a good name for a class.

Comment: Ok, I get what your saying! I didn't catch it at first. I will go do that right now. Thank you, for all your help on this.

Comment: @Colby - you shouldn't declare it as `final`

Comment: So close it's killing me. lol

I'm having trouble with the "mp =MediaPlayer line"

mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, sound);
error = "The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int)"


mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sound); 
error = The final local variable mp cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type