# Android Button setOnClickListener Design

Tags: android, button, design-patterns, onclicklistener

I am building an Android Application. I've noticed that I am creating many repetitions of code similar to this in each of my classes:

```
Button buttonX = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonXName);
// Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
buttonX.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //DO SOMETHING! {RUN SOME FUNCTION ... DO CHECKS... ETC}
    } 
});
```

I now have fifteen buttons and this is making my code ugly. Does anyone have a class or some examples on how I can turn all these codes into something more efficient, so I can:

1. Create the button object `{Button buttonX (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonXName);}`
2. Set the listener `{buttonX.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()}`
3. Determine if it was clicked `{public void onClick(View v)}`
4. Then run specific code for each button?

If anyone knows anything, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Try [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you're targeting 1.6 or later, you can use the [android:onClick xml attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick) to remove some of the repetitive code. See [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/ui-framework-changes-in-android-16.html) by Romain Guy.

```
<Button 
   android:height="wrap_content"
   android:width="wrap_content"
   android:onClick="myClickHandler" />
```

And in the Java class, use these below lines of code:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void myClickHandler(View target) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: weird, this didn't work with my Dialog. I got an exception saying the handler didn't exist, but I did definitely define the handler!

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere I think it search the view in the activity context. Handlers are out of game.

Comment: @dgmltn is it good practice to 'let view know about Activity internals' ?

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you. Lambda code and inline functions is hard to read for an old guy like me.

Answer (score 28):

Implement OnClickListener() on your Activity...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
}
```

For each button use...

```
buttonX.setOnClickListener(this);
```

In your Activity onClick() method test for which button it is...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (View.equals(buttonX))
        // Do something
}
```

Also in onClick you could use view.getId() to get the resource ID and then use that in a switch/case block to identify each button and perform the relevant action.

Comment: Is this really an improvement?

Comment: @Corey Sunwold: It's all pretty subjective but using setOnClickListener(this); is a lot less ugly and reduces the button creation part of the code by not having inline onClick() declarations. Having only one onCLick() code block and, in particular, using a switch/case code block to identify which button is pressed puts an easy test in a separate area of main code. More than that, each 'case' could simply call a method in a 'helper' class located elsewhere. I can think of another way or two of doing things but code still has to go somewhere.

Comment: Squonk: That makes more sense, I hadn't considered it from a testability standpoint (probably should have). Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

### Android lambada solution

```
public void registerButtons(){
    register(R.id.buttonName1, ()-> {/*Your code goes here*/});
    register(R.id.buttonName2, ()-> {/*Your code goes here*/});
    register(R.id.buttonName3, ()-> {/*Your code goes here*/});
}

private void register(int buttonResourceId, Runnable r){
    findViewById(buttonResourceId).setOnClickListener(v -> r.run());
}
```

### Switch case solution solution

```
public void registerButtons(){
    register(R.id.buttonName1);
    register(R.id.buttonName2);
    register(R.id.buttonName3);
}

private void register(int buttonResourceId){
    findViewById(buttonResourceId).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
}

private OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonName1:
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                break;
            case R.id.buttonName2:
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                break;
            case View.NO_ID:
            default:
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 11):

Since `setOnClickListener` is defined on `View` not `Button`, if you don't need the variable for something else, you could make it a little terser like this:

```
findViewById(R.id.buttonXName).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //DO SOMETHING! {RUN SOME FUNCTION ... DO CHECKS... ETC}
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use array to handle several button click listener in android like this:
here i am setting button click listener for n buttons by using array as:

```
Button btn[] = new Button[n];
```

NOTE: n is a constant positive integer

Code example:

```
//class androidMultipleButtonActions 
package a.b.c.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class androidMultipleButtonActions extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    Button btn[] = new Button[3];

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        
        btn[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        btn[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button2);
        btn[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button3);
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            btn[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        }           
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == findViewById(R.id.Button1)){
            //do here what u wanna do.
        }
        else if(v == findViewById(R.id.Button2)){
            //do here what u wanna do.
        }
        else if(v == findViewById(R.id.Button3)){
            //do here what u wanna do.
        }
    }
}
```

Note: First write an main.xml file if u dont know how to write please mail to:
wesagnd@yahoo.com

Answer (score 3):

I think you can usually do what you need in a loop, which is much better than many `onClick` methods if it can be done.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543361/imagebutton-soundboard-android-app/5543557#5543557) for a demonstration of how to use a loop for a similar problem. How you construct your loop will depend on the needs of your `onClick` functions and how similar they are to one another. The end result is much less repetitive code that is easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Implement Activity with `View.OnClickListener` like below.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_options);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int id = view.getId();

        switch (id) {

            case R.id.button:

                  // Write your code here first button

                break;

             case R.id.button2:

                  // Write your code here for second button

                break;

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_options);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int id = view.getId();

        switch (id) {

            case R.id.button:

                  // Write your code here first button

                break;

             case R.id.button2:

                  // Write your code here for second button

                break;

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button is Working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```