# NoSuchMethod exception for Button onClick

Tags: android, button, nosuchmethoderror

I have an Android app that's testing a JNI library. The app has a button with an `onClick` handler:

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...
    <Button
        ...
        android:id="@+id/btnGenerate"           
        android:text="@string/btn_generate"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:onClick="btnGenerate_onClick"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, in the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...

    protected void btnGenerate_onClick(View view)
    {
        // Do some work...
        String str = <some result>; 

        final TextView lblNumbers = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblNumbers);
        if(lblNumbers != null)
        {
            lblNumbers.setText(str);
        }
    }
}
```

When I tap the button, I receive a `NoSuchMethodException`.

I lifted the solution from [Android Button setOnClickListener Design Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588804/android-button-setonclicklistener-design-help), so I'm not sure why its not working.

Why is the code causing a `NoSuchMethod` exception?

---

```
09-05 07:20:57.417: W/dalvikvm(10563): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aae228)
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method btnGenerate_onClick(View) in the activity class com.cryptopp.prng.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btnGenerate'
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3069)
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14393)
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: btnGenerate_onClick [class android.view.View]
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3062)
09-05 07:20:57.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10563):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: make btnGenerate_onClick(View view) to public

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method should be `public` so that it can be seen from outside.

Edit:
Here is Android source code for handling `onClick` attribute - [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/view/View.java?av=f#3789)

In there you can see that it's trying to get the method you passed as a value for the attribute through `getClass().getMethod()` on the `Context` object.

`getMethod` judgung by Oracle site "Returns a Method object that reflects the specified public member method of the class or interface represented by this Class object", so the method must be `public`.

Comment: +1. The documentation mentions `...must correspond to a public method...` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Its odd that the program can't access its own methods unless they are public. Its even odder that I got an irrelevant error message. If the VM would have given me a meaningful error message, then I would not have wasted your time (sorry about that).

Comment: @Craig - not the documentation I visited: [Button Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html). Why would the doc folks expect someone to visit a page on `View` class when working with a `Button` class???

Comment: @jww There is no overridden documentation for `android:onClick` in the `Button` class. There is a link, however, to the documentation in the `View` class. This is very common when a class is a subclass of another component, avoiding duplicate documentation.