# Why can these symbols not be found?

Tags: java, android, button, android-mediaplayer

OK, having an android studios issue this time around. Just for note, this is not an assignment I have to turn in I'm simply trying to complete the example in the chapter.

It appears that the error is happening with the bUkulele and bDrums variables in the PlayMusic.java file but I can't figure out why.

```
package net.androidbootcamp.alohamusic;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PlayMusic extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button1, button2;
    MediaPlayer mpUkulele, mpDrums;
    int playing;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_music);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUkulele);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDrums);
        button1.setOnClickListener(bUkulele);
        button2.setOnClickListener(bDrums);
        mpUkulele = new MediaPlayer();
        mpUkulele = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ukulele);
        mpDrums = new MediaPlayer();
        mpDrums = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.drums);
        playing = 0;

        Button.OnClickListener bUkulele = new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V) {
                switch (playing) {
                    case 0:
                        mpUkulele.start();
                        playing = 1;
                        button1.setText("Pause Ukulele Song");
                        button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mpUkulele.pause();
                        playing = 0;
                        button1.setText("Play Ukulele Song");
                        button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                }
            }

            ;

            Button.OnClickListener bDrums = new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View V) {
                    switch (playing) {
                        case 0:
                            mpDrums.start();
                            playing = 1;
                            button2.setText("Pause Drums Song");
                            button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            mpDrums.pause();
                            playing = 0;
                            button2.setText("Play Drums Song");
                            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
        };
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

"error: cannot find symbol variable bUkulele"
"error: cannot find symbol variable bDrums"

I've been back through the chapter but I can't find any other instances where these variables are either created or called except in this .java file.

Is it possible the code should be different due to a newer version of Android Studio because I am aware that our textbook is rather dated?

Comment: Try moving the definition of those variables before the statements where they are used.

Comment: Totally off topic, but what's going to happen when another class in the package `alohamusic` sets `playing` to, say, 3?

Answer (score 3):

> It appears that the error is happening with the bUkulele and bDrums variables in the PlayMusic.java file but I can't figure out why.

That's because you are trying to use the objects before you defined them.

Explanation with a real world example :

John is walking

John eats the apple

John grabs an apple

What is going to eat John? Anything because he didn't grab the apple yet, so I recommend to you to put those objects before you calling them.

So then the apple can be eaten by John :)

Btw: There's a lot of easier ways to create a `setOnClickListener()` take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588804/android-button-setonclicklistener-design)

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Or shall I improve my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are trying to add the bUkulele and bDrums variables as onClickListeners before you are defining them. If you move their initialization to before you use the variables, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you everyone for the suggestions.

Just for the record I did attempt to define the variables beforehand. It was the first suggestion Android Studio gave me and it didn't work. I got the same error.

However, I did find the problem. Turns out some brackets were in the wrong place at the end-that was all. I moved them around and the program runs perfectly now.