# Reduce function and avoid repetition

Tags: java, android-studio, if-statement, switch-statement

I want to reduce the size of my function, and therefore avoid repetition.
By building a single function that contains all my commands at the same time.
the "if" function is present in three different configurations, is it possible to adjust everything to be able to write it once?
Can we do the same for "else" functions?
If you have any suggestions, don't hesitate, I'm new to Java so my level is not yet advanced enough.

```
   if (text.substring(15, 18).contains("A"))
            {
                R2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picto_rouge);
            }
            else {
                R2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picto_vert);
            }
             R2.setOnClickListener(a -> {

                 setContentView(R.layout.activity_autodiagnostic_repartiteur);
                 {
                     Repartiteur = findViewById(R.id.Repartiteur);
                     Repartiteur.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.repartiteur2);

                     BottomNavigationView bandeauNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bandeau_navigation);
                     bandeauNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.accueil);
                     bandeauNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
                         switch (item.getItemId()) {
                             case R.id.accueil:
                                 return true;
                             case R.id.commerce:
                                 startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PageCommercial.class));
                                 overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                                 return true;
                             case R.id.services:
                                 startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Support.class));
                                 overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                                 return true;
                             case R.id.info:
                                 startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Info.class));
                                 overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                                 return true;
                         }

                         return false;
                     });
                 }
             });



            if (text.substring(19, 22).contains("A"))
            {
                R3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picto_rouge);
            }
            else {
                R3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picto_vert);
            }
            R3.setOnClickListener(a -> {

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_autodiagnostic_repartiteur);
                {
                    Repartiteur = findViewById(R.id.Repartiteur);
                    Repartiteur.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.repartiteur3);

                    BottomNavigationView bandeauNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bandeau_navigation);
                    bandeauNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.accueil);
                    bandeauNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.accueil:
                                return true;
                            case R.id.commerce:
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PageCommercial.class));
                                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.services:
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Support.class));
                                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.info:
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Info.class));
                                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                                return true;
                        }

                        return false;
                    });
                }
            });
            
            if (text.substring(23, 26).contains("A"))
            {
                R4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picto_rouge);
            }
            else {
                R4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picto_vert);
            }
            R4.setOnClickListener(a -> {

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_autodiagnostic_repartiteur);
                {
                    Repartiteur = findViewById(R.id.Repartiteur);
                    Repartiteur.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.repartiteur4);

                    BottomNavigationView bandeauNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bandeau_navigation);
                    bandeauNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.accueil);
                    bandeauNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.accueil:
                                return true;
                            case R.id.commerce:
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PageCommercial.class));
                                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.services:
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Support.class));
                                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.info:
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Info.class));
                                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                                return true;
                        }

                        return false;
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: implement setonclicklistener to the class and in the onClick() method add a switchcase based on the view-id it would be a way cleaner code

Comment: you can show me an example of how to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588804/android-button-setonclicklistener-design, check this

Answer (score 0):

Move your the logic of your click listeners into a single private method:

```
private void processClick(int newBackgroundResource) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_autodiagnostic_repartiteur);
    {
        Repartiteur = findViewById(R.id.Repartiteur);
        Repartiteur.setBackgroundResource(newBackgroundResource);

        BottomNavigationView bandeauNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bandeau_navigation);
        bandeauNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.accueil);
        bandeauNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.accueil:
                    return true;
                case R.id.commerce:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PageCommercial.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.services:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Support.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.info:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Info.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

Now you can shorten your original code to this:

```
if (text.substring(15, 18).contains("A")) {
    R2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picto_rouge);
} else {
    R2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picto_vert);
}

R2.setOnClickListener(a -> processClick(R.drawable.repartiteur2));

if (text.substring(19, 22).contains("A")) {
    R3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picto_rouge);
} else {
    R3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picto_vert);
}

R3.setOnClickListener(a -> processClick(R.drawable.repartiteur3));

if (text.substring(23, 26).contains("A")) {
    R4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picto_rouge);
} else {
    R4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picto_vert);
}

R4.setOnClickListener(a -> processClick(R.drawable.repartiteur4));
```