# setOnTouchListener points to a null

Tags: java, android-studio

I've been working on this code for a bit and i can't comprehend why it isn't working.
I feel like I've declared the button correctly but I guess there still is a problem in my code.

```
flecheDroite = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    flecheDroite.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "droite",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Why can't the text "droite" be shown when button is pressed ?

Comment: Are you sure an `ImageButton` with `android:id="@+id/imageButton"` exists in your layout file?

Comment: @ThéoRousselot-Pailley I think you have to learn android again because you have to use `setOnClickListner` not `.setOnTouchListener`. see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/5588804/16765223

Comment: @RickyMo Thanks for the answer. Yes I'm sure, I've checked a hundred times now. That's why I don't get why I'm still getting a null pointer exception...

Comment: @MDev I'm just starting android so I'm not very good at it. I wanted to use a setOnTouchListener because I want to be able to show a message when button is pressed and change the message when its realeased. Is that possible with setOnClickListener ? Thanks for the answer

Comment: @ThéoRousselot-Pailley yeah it is possbile

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
flecheDroite = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
flecheDroite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "droite",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```